# Merging dataframes by columns where some columns exist in both dataset but some do not

Tags: r, matrix, merge, na

Suppose you have two datasets, `x` and `y`:

```
x=matrix(c(1,2,55,3,2,1,0,NA,NA,3,NA,333,NA,9,NA),5,3)
colnames(x)=c(1133131,12442141,20100063)
rownames(x)=c(1,2,3,4,5)

y=matrix(c(8,1,3,41,131,NA,4141,NA,124,NA,213,NA,128,NA,2,NA,1241,2),3,6)
colnames(y)=c(1133131,2422342,555555,33323242,20100063,23325600009)
rownames(y)=c(6,7,8)
```

I want to merge them so that all columns are present in the final dataset, and the data is filled in where it exists, and `NA` where it is not.  So if one is not present in the other dataset, I want all its values to be `NA` for that part.

So basically I want the final output to be:

```
merged:     upc
    days    1133131, 12442141, 2422342, 555555, 33323242, 20100063, 23325600009
       1           1         1      NA
       2           2         0      NA
       3           55       NA      NA
       4           3        NA      NA            ...etc
       5           2         3      NA
       6           8        NA      41
       7           1        NA      131
       8           3        NA      NA
```

Comment: First decide if you want to merge dataframes (like in title) or matrices (from example).

Comment: The rownames are distinct in `x` and `y`; if this will always happen in your data sets, the solution is easier, and actually, would perhaps better be called an `rbind` in R-lingo rather than a `merge`.  Can you clarify if those rownames will always be distinct?

Comment: Yes, they will always be distinct, but they will have different width so rbind(x,y) won't product the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plyr.fill

```
library(plyr)

# With matrices
rbind.fill.matrix(x, y)

# With dataframes
rbind.fill(as.data.frame(x), as.data.frame(y))
```

Comment: This is not what they are looking for. Note that they're desired output has only one row corresponding to days = 1.

Comment: @joran Actually I am not sure. It seems for me that days corresponds to rownames from in input. Value 1 one occurs twice in column 1133131 in input and desired output.

Comment: I agree with @zero323, this looks like what they want.  Might depend on the rows being unique in `x` and `y`, but my solution does too.

Comment: @zero323, maybe add the output from one of these, that will help as well

Comment: So that was my bad, what if the row names were different than the rownumbers, like rather instead they were dates?

Comment: Actually I ust renamed the rows manually from the original matrices, this works fine.

Comment: You can convert to a `data.frame` by calling `as.data.frame` just once after doing `rbind.fill.matrix`. It's a costly operation when you've too many data.frames..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `base` way to do this, just by making a new matrix and filling it in appropriately.  It depends on the rows being unique in `x` and `y` though.

```
cs <- sort(unique(c(colnames(x), colnames(y))))
rs <- c(rownames(x), rownames(y))
xy <- array(NA, dim=c(length(rs), length(cs)), dimnames=list(days=rs, upc=cs))
xy[1:nrow(x), colnames(x)] <- x
xy[nrow(x) + 1:nrow(y), colnames(y)] <- y
xy
##     upc
## days 1133131 12442141 20100063 23325600009 2422342 33323242 555555
##    1       1        1       NA          NA      NA       NA     NA
##    2       2        0      333          NA      NA       NA     NA
##    3      55       NA       NA          NA      NA       NA     NA
##    4       3       NA        9          NA      NA       NA     NA
##    5       2        3       NA          NA      NA       NA     NA
##    6       8       NA      128          NA      41       NA   4141
##    7       1       NA       NA        1241     131      213     NA
##    8       3       NA        2           2      NA       NA    124
```